# Azure Logic Apps Decode EDIFACT

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, edifact

I try to decode a EDIFACT D96A order, I created the partners en agreement and uploaded the ORDERS schema and linked it in the agreement. However I still get error bellow. While the count is right:

> exception: "Error encountered during parsing. The Edifact transaction set with id '1' contained in interchange (without group) with id '03221373', with sender id '95750460800515', receiver id '3016603550108' is being suspended with following errors:
>
> Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error) 70:
> Error: 2 (Miscellaneous error) 71: Transaction Set or Group Control Number Mismatch
> Error: 3 (Miscellaneous error) 29: Invalid count specified at interchange, group, or message levels

I found in another tread that I need to fill in the fields `UNG2.1 (APP SENDER ID)` and `UNG2.2 (APP SENDER CODE QUALIFIER)` but I'm not sure with which value.

EDIFACT order:

```
UNA:+.? '
UNB+UNOC:3+{removed}:14+{removed}:14+160126:0414+EW552565597'
UNH+EW41193373+ORDERS:D:96A:UN:EAN008'
BGM+220+806256270+9'
DTM+4:20160124:102'
DTM+137:20160126:102'
DTM+2:20160205:102'
FTX+AAI+++Réappro auto'
FTX+ZZZ+++FRANCO VALEUR:250'
FTX+INV+++60 jours nets'
NAD+BY+{removed}::9'
NAD+DP+{removed}::9'
NAD+SU+{removed}::9'
RFF+API:39164'
NAD+IV+{removed}::9'
CUX+2:EUR:9'
LIN+1++{removed}:EN'
IMD+F+DSC+:::{removed}'
QTY+21:6'
MOA+203:34.5'
PRI+AAA:5.75'
RFF+PD:9606'
DTM+194:20151222:102'
DTM+206:20160125:102'
RFF+API:39164'
LIN+2++{removed}:EN'
IMD+F+DSC+:::{removed}'
QTY+21:6'
MOA+203:34.5'
PRI+AAA:5.75'
RFF+API:39164'
LIN+3++{removed}:EN'
IMD+F+DSC+:::{removed}'
QTY+21:6'
MOA+203:34.5'
PRI+AAA:5.75'
RFF+API:39164'
LIN+4++{removed}:EN'
IMD+F+DSC+:::{removed}'
QTY+21:3'
MOA+203:86.4'
PRI+AAA:28.8'
RFF+PD:9606'
DTM+194:20151222:102'
DTM+206:20160125:102'
RFF+API:39164'
LIN+5++{removed}:EN'
IMD+F+DSC+:::{removed}'
QTY+21:6'
MOA+203:172.8'
PRI+AAA:28.8'
RFF+API:39164'
UNS+S'
MOA+86:362.7'
CNT+2:5'
UNT+54+EW41193373'
UNZ+1+EW552565597'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set UNH2.5 to EAN008 in your Agreement, also you have to modify your schema Root Node to add _EAN008.

You have the detail here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-edifact_inputfile_unh2.5